# Source code? "where i will get source file"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am new in ruby. i search a lot about ruby on google and now i now that its open source so i think that we can edit code or learn code. so friends please help me to get source code of ruby i am using ruby 1.8.7 with rails 3.0.7 and ubuntu 11.10 so where can i find source code in my system.

And if i will edit anything so how can i share it to all?

and also give me some information about singletone property of ruby i am aware about java so you can take reference of that.

and can u explain this code

```
class Object
   # The hidden singleton lurks behind everyone
   def metaclass; class << self; self; end; end
   def meta_eval &blk; metaclass.instance_eval &blk; end
end
```

Comment: These are at least three different questions, and should be asked as such.

Comment: Ya i understand that so sorry for this but can you explain these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Ruby source code in different places: http://ruby-lang.org or https://github.com/ruby/ruby

If you create a user at github you can share your source code with others as well or you can use the ruby bugtracker which is listed on the ruby-lang website. Have fun with Ruby!